# preg_match_all requires 3 parameters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Here is my code:

```
$myText = "@koraytugaykoray@";
$mypattern = "@k.*y@";
echo "<br />";

preg_match_all($mypattern, $myText);
```

I am getting:

> Warning: preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in C:\DocumentRoot\Framework\index.php on line 12

But according to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php , this should be fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In versions before 5.4.0 the 3rd argument to `preg_match_all()` was not optional:

> 5.4.0   The matches parameter became optional.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: Sorry dumb question... Thanks.